# Why Android Studio Emulator cannot use my laptop webcam?

Tags: android-camera, webcam, android-virtual-device

- Android Studio 3.0.1
- Windows 10
- Java v9.0

Please excuse my level of a-maturity. But, I cannot use laptop webcam as front or back camera in Emulator, although, I set it in AVD Manager, Virtual Device Config setting. In API level 23, I have camera App, when I open it in the Emulator, it says, "**cannot connect to camera**". On API level 26 and 27, there is no camera app.
Also, I am sure, my Webcam is defined and active in Windows 10, device Manager.

I would be really thankful, if any body can help me in this regard.
Also, here is the [log][1] file when I open camera app in Emulator.

There are some similar questions about Emulator Camera in here, I tried them but I got no result.

When I start Emulator, my camera LED indicator start to flash in the beginning. But it turns off after a few seconds.

```
  [1]: https://pastebin.com/jZyenaU0
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/behFz.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNgEQ.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S4QG.png
```